# How to Deploy Verdaccio through App Service and Integrate with AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, verdaccio

I have deployed the verdaccio container in APP service and sucessfully deployed and able to login. Now question is how to integrate with Active Directory to login to verdaccio?

I have tried to mount the configuration file with active directory configurations but it is not working.

Comment: I have achieved it by using docker file and I have written a blog. Hope for someone may help.
https://medium.com/@kirankucharkanti/configure-verdaccio-to-work-with-azure-active-directory-a04eb24ade73